# Read chunks of XML data in between <product></product> tags and insert fields into SQL Database

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I am using following VB.Net Code to download large XML file ( 64 MB ) using VB.NET and save it locally, which works great, the XML feed looks like below.

My xml feed url is **http://www.topbuy.com.au/tbcart/tbadmin/datafeed/shoppingcom.xml**

I am trying to achieve and need suggestions is instead of Downloading the file and store it locally, is there a way in VB.Net to read chunks of XML data in between  tags and insert fields into SQL Database. Any examples, what should i change in the below code **( VB.Net)**

```
Dim remoteUri As String = "http://www.topbuy.com.au/tbcart/tbadmin/datafeed/"
Dim fileName As String = "shoppingcom.xml"
Dim myStringWebResource As String = Nothing
' Create a new WebClient instance.
Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()
' Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename. Because DownloadFile 
'requires a fully qualified resource name, concatenate the domain with the Web resource file name.
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName
Console.WriteLine("Downloading File ""{0}"" from ""{1}"" ......." + ControlChars.Cr + ControlChars.Cr, fileName, myStringWebResource)
' The DownloadFile() method downloads the Web resource and saves it into the current file-system folder.
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName)
Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded file ""{0}"" from ""{1}""", fileName, myStringWebResource)
Console.WriteLine((ControlChars.Cr + "Downloaded file saved in the following file system folder:" + ControlChars.Cr + ControlChars.Tab + Application.StartupPath))
```

**XML**

```
<Products>
<Product><MPN><![CDATA[INK-PE-009]]></MPN><Manufacturer><![CDATA[Epson]]></Manufacturer><ProductName><![CDATA[Epson T009 Colour Compatible Inkjet Cartridge]]></ProductName><ProductURL><![CDATA[http://www.topbuy.com.au/tbcart/pc/Epson-T009-Colour-Compatible-Inkjet-Cartridge-p3343.htm?utm_source=TopBuy_ShoppingCom&utm_content=&utm_medium=cpc&dismode=1&utm_campaign=TBDF-XX10421]]></ProductURL><ProductType><![CDATA[Compatible Ink Cartridges]]></ProductType><ImageURL><![CDATA[http://www2.topbuy.com.au/tbcart/pc/catalog/General/TBDF-XX10421_1.jpg]]></ImageURL><Price>4.09</Price><OriginalPrice>9</OriginalPrice><Category><![CDATA[Consumables->Compatible Ink Cartridges]]></Category><ProductDescription><![CDATA[$4.05 Cash Price see store for detailsRelated Brand  EpsonOriginal Cartridge Equivalent T009Related Printers STYLUS 1270, STYLUS 1280, STYLUS 1290, STYLUS 3300C, STYLUS PHOTO 1270, STYLUS PHOTO 1290, STYLUS PHOTO 1290 silverThis cartridge works in the following printers  Epson Stylus Photo 1270/1280Please check the name (code) of the cartridge in your printer before ordering to ensure that it matches the name of the cartridges you are ordering from us. In some instances a printer can take more than one cartridge type and ...]]></ProductDescription><Stock>Y</Stock><ShippingCost>10</ShippingCost><StockDescription>No.1 OZ SUPERSTORE AUS WARRANTY FAST SHIPPING</StockDescription><Condition>Brand New</Condition></Product>
<Product><MPN><![CDATA[INK-PE-013]]></MPN><Manufacturer><![CDATA[Epson]]></Manufacturer><ProductName><![CDATA[Epson T013 Black Compatible Inkjet Cartridge]]></ProductName><ProductURL><![CDATA[http://www.topbuy.com.au/tbcart/pc/Epson-T013-Black-Compatible-Inkjet-Cartridge-p3345.htm?utm_source=TopBuy_ShoppingCom&utm_content=&utm_medium=cpc&dismode=1&utm_campaign=TBDF-XX10423]]></ProductURL><ProductType><![CDATA[Compatible Ink Cartridges]]></ProductType><ImageURL><![CDATA[http://www2.topbuy.com.au/tbcart/pc/catalog/General/TBDF-XX10423_1.jpg]]></ImageURL><Price>2.09</Price><OriginalPrice>5</OriginalPrice><Category><![CDATA[Consumables->Compatible Ink Cartridges]]></Category><ProductDescription><![CDATA[$2.07 Cash Price see store for detailsRelated Brand  EpsonOriginal Cartridge Equivalent T013Related Printers STYLUS COLOR 480, STYLUS COLOR 580, STYLUS COLOR C20, STYLUS COLOR C40, STYLUS COLOUR 480, STYLUS COLOUR 580, STYLUS COLOUR C20UX, STYLUS COLOUR C40SX, STYLUS COLOUR C40UXThis cartridge works in the following printers  Epson Stylus Colour 480/580Please check the name (code) of the cartridge in your printer before ordering to ensure that it matches the name of the cartridges you are ordering from us. In some instances a ...]]></ProductDescription><Stock>Y</Stock><ShippingCost>10</ShippingCost><StockDescription>No.1 OZ SUPERSTORE AUS WARRANTY FAST SHIPPING</StockDescription><Condition>Brand New</Condition></Product>
</Products>
```

Comment: 64MB is not that large. Your code will be much easier (to write, read and understand) if you can use `System.Xml.Linq` instead of using an `XmlReader`. Xml.Linq code is much much more maintainable. So... If memory is not an issue, consider using it.

Answer (score 0):

Use an XmlReader class with a stream, something like (apologies for a C# example but my C# is better than my VB):

```
        WebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        using(Stream stream = (await webRequest.GetResponseAsync()).GetResponseStream())
        using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, new XmlReaderSettings() { Async = true }))
        {
            // Use the XmlReader to move through the elements of the stream
        }
```

This will pull down the data as needed without needing to store it locally. If you find what you are looking for, you will only download and parse as much of the stream that you need.

Note that this example uses the `await` keyword  and so should be in an `async` method.